# how to use awk/sed to deal with these two files to get a result that I want

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to use `awk/sed` to deal with two files(a.txt and b.txt) below and get the result
`cat a.txt`

```
a UK
b Japan
c China
d Korea
e US
```

And `cat b.txt` results

```
c Russia
e Canada
```

The result that I want is as below:

```
a UK
b Japan
c Russia
d Korea
e Canada
```

Comment: [edit] your question and use the `{}` button to format your input, output, and code.

Comment: Thanks . I have tried use awk to solve this problem. However I am newbie for awk. Can you guys give me some hints? Thank you

Comment: so if there's conflict, i.e. `c China` & `c Russia`, in a.txt & b.txt, force to adopt the content in b.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$NF;next} {printf("%s %s\n",$1,$1 in A?A[$1]:$NF)}' b.txt a.txt
```

Checking here condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE only when first file(b.txt) is being read. Then creating an array named A whose index is $1 and have the value last column. Then using printf for printing 2 strings where first string is $1 and another is if $1 of a.txt is present in array A then print array A's value whose index is $1 else print last column of a.tzt itself.

EDIT: as OP had carriage characters into Input_files so please remove them by following too.

```
tr -d '\r' < b.txt > temp_b.txt && mv temp_b.txt b.txt
```

Comment: You've got the right idea but - Why obfuscate your code by using an array named "A" to represent the contents of a file named "b", especially when the OTHER file is named "a"? Don't use all upper case variable names for all the usual reasons discussed ad-nauseum online. Do parenthesize your ternary expressions for portability across awk versions (some awks  will give a syntax error otherwise in some contexts). Why use printf when a simple print will do? Why use $NF instead of just $2 when your code relies on there only being 2 fields? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44311894/1745001.

Comment: sometimes the first line not be changed and rest of them are fine. I don't know why, could u give me some hints

Comment: Please show us examples, we could help more on same then.

Comment: I notice that If I put empty line as first line on b file, It will work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: could you please try to check if there are any carriage characters present into Input_files by doing, "cat -v a.txt" and "cat -v b.txt". If you see carriage returns then remove them by "tr -d '\r' < a.txt > temp_a.txt && mv temp_a.txt a.txt". Let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Hello Ravinder, u r right, it show "M-oM-;M-?" before the first line.

Comment: cool then , you could remove them and then code should fly :) Enjoy learning

Comment: Thank you so much  @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

First fill aray/hash `a` with complete row (`$0`) and use first column (`$1`) from this row as index. Finally, print all elements of array/hash `a` with a loop.

```
awk '{a[$1]=$0} END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
a UK
b Japan
c Russia
d Korea
e Canada
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below one-liner:

```
join -a 1 -a 2 a.txt <( awk '{print $1, "--", $0, "--"}' < b.txt ) | sed 's/ --$//' | awk -F ' -- ' '{print $NF}'
```

We use awk to prefix each line in b.txt with a key and `--` to give us a split point later:

```
<( awk '{print $1, "--", $0, "--"}' < b.txt )
```

Use the join command to join the files on common keys. The `-a 1` option tells the command to

```
join -a 1 -a 2 a.txt <( awk '{print $1, "--", $0, "--"}' < b.txt )
```

Use sed to remove the `--` parts that are on some end of lines:

```
sed 's/ --$//'
```

Use awk to print the last item on each line:

```
awk -F ' -- ' '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: or print first and last column: `join -a 1 file1 file2 | awk '{print $1,$NF}'`

Comment: @Cyrus : That assumes that the input files only contain one word for each key. `South Korea` would just result with `Korea`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{b[$1]=$2;next} {print $1, ($1 in b ? b[$1] : $2)}' b.txt a.txt
a UK
b Japan
c Russia
d Korea
e Canada
```